# Someone tried to access a list of hundreds of standard website urls in a go, is it a cause of concern

Tags: security, hacking

I was just checking my website logs today and found that someone accessed my website for a list of hundreds of standard urls that almost every 3rd or 4th website developed on a standard platform contains. IP was same and it was done in a minutes timeframe so definitely some program was behind this. I am a little worried, I have a few questions in mind.

1. what was his actual intention for doing this?
2. Is it a cause of concern?
3. What possible security leaks it could provide to an attacker?
4. And how to avoid such attempts, shall I blacklist that particular
   IP?

For note: I have developed this website myself so almost 98% of urls in his list were not accessible.

I am providing portion of that log for your better understanding (first line of log is his 1st landing page, I have masked his IP for posting it here with XX.XX.XXX.XXX):

```
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /Basket.aspx    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /Login.aspx Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /CFIDE/administrator/enter.cfm  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /cfdocs/dochome.htm Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /CFIDE/wizards/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /store/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /jackrabbit-webapp/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /jackrabbit/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /svn/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /roller/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /blog/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /roller-ui/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /admin/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /manager/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /manager/html   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /host-manager/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /host-manager/html  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /server-status  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /server-status/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /server-1-status/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /a/server-status    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /backend/server-status  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /debug/server-status    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /admin/server-status    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /status/perl/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /status Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /status/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /mod_status Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /rproxy-status  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /apache-rproxy-status   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /mync-server-status Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /xampp/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /security/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /samples/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /cms/typo3conf/ext/goof_fotoboek/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /ShoppingCart.aspx  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /checkout/ShoppingCart.aspx Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /cart/ShoppingCart.aspx Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /catalog/ShoppingCart.aspx  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /estore/ShoppingCart.aspx   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /order/ShoppingCart.aspx    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /pages/ShoppingCart.aspx    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /shopping/ShoppingCart.aspx Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /shoppingcart/ShoppingCart.aspx Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /store/ShoppingCart.aspx    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /login.jsp  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /fisheye/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /cgi-bin/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /awstats/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /stats/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /awstats/stats/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /stats/awstats/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /awstats/cgi-bin/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /stats/cgi-bin/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /statistics/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /awstats-cgi/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /batavi/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /README Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /bitweaver/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /bitweaver/README   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /webalizer/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /+CSCOE+/logon.html Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /+webvpn+/index.html    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /admin/public/index.html    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /login/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /login.asp  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /_utils/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /_utils/index.html  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /cpcommerce/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /cubecart/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /pinnacle/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /login.php  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /pinnacle/login.php Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /kart/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /dotnetnuke/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /dnn/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /cms/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /drupal5/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /drupal6/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /drupal7/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /drupal/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /GScart/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /cart/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /productcart/pc/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /productcart/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /pc/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /store/pc/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /horde/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /webmail/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /horde-webmail/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /horde2/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /horde3/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /horde4/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /onecms/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /OneCMS/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /vsadmin/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /web-console/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /admin-console/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /console/App.html   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /jmx-console/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /jenkins/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /wp/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /wordpress/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /joomla/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /content/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /livecart/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /mambo/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /cms/typo3conf/ext/mk_anydropdownmenu/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /certsrv/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /certsrv/Default.asp    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /certsrv/certcarc.asp   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /certsrv/certckpn.asp   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /certsrv/certrqbi.asp   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /certsrv/certrqma.asp   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /certsrv/certfnsh.asp   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /certsrv/certrqus.asp   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /certsrv/certrqxt.asp   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /default.aspx   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /internalsite/InternalError.asp Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /exchweb/bin/auth/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /exchange/logon.asp Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /owa/auth/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /SMSReporting_XYZ/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /ReportsTitle.asp   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /ReportsBody.asp    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /ts/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /ts/en-US/Default.aspx  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /tfs/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /TFS/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /lang/en/docs/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /moodle/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /webcart/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /webcart11/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /webcart-lite/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /mt/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /mt/readme.html Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /mt-static/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /mt-static/readme.html  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /cgi-bin/mt/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /cgi-bin/mt/mt-wizard.cgi   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /cgi-bin/mt/readme.html Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /index.cgi  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /enter.cgi  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /bugzilla/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /mybb   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /cgiwrap/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /cgi-bin/cgiwrap/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /gw/webacc  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /servlet/webacc Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /myinfochat/servlet/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /eagent/servlet/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /servlet/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /opencart/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /acegilogin.jsp Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /opennms/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /opennms/login.jsp  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /opennms/acegilogin.jsp Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /em/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /CHANGELOG  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /oscommerce/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /oscommerce/CHANGELOG   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /login_up.php3  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /We_Accept_PayPal.html  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /commconfig.cgi Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /commerce.html  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /commerce.cgi   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpfusion/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /php-fusion/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpBB3/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpBB/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /forum/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpcart/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /lists/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phplist/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpMyAdmin/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpmyadmin/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phproxy/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.6/public_html/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.6/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.61/public_html/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.61/ Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.6.1/public_html/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.6.1/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.6.2/public_html/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.6.2/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.6.5/public_html/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.6.5/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-065/public_html/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-065/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.7.1/public_html/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.7.1/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.7.2/public_html/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.7.2/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.8/public_html/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.8/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.8.1/public_html/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash-0.8.1/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash/public_html/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpslash/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /phpSlash/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /projectpier/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /qcodo/assets/js/_core/_qc_packed.js    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /qcodo/assets/php/_core/error_already_rendered_page.php Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /railo-context/admin/server.cfm Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /railo-context/admin/web.cfm    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /422.html   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /403.html   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /500.html   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /root_page.html Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /cgi_root.html  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /shellinabox/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /shellinabox/root_page.html Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /shellinabox/cgi_root.html  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /cart   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /checkout   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /silverstripe/  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /sit/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /sit/README Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /smarty/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /change_log.txt Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
XX.XX.XXX.XXX   /NEWS   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
```

Comment: I see no reason to protect the guilty :)

Comment: This isn't actually a duplicate of the linked question; the linked question is trying to execute known vulnerabilities in PhpMyAdmin, while this is clearly a case of fingerprinting the server: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Fingerprint_Web_Server_(OTG-INFO-002) Basically, the attacker is trying to determine what software is running, which he can then use to determine whether exploits are available, perhaps using Armitage or something like that: http://www.fastandeasyhacking.com/ While not a major source of concern, it is a good reminder to keep up-to-date with the latest security updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1: What do you think? Hacking.

2: No.

3: A list of software you run. All of those likely had known exploits at one point.

4: Take your server off the internet. If people can not reach it, they can not try it. ONLY way. YOu put a server on the internet, someone WILL try to see whether you run crap software. There is no way from stopping people from doing that.

Comment: So you mean to say this is a routine thing that happens on web. And I need not to pay attention to such activities?

Comment: Well, you keep yourself secured (patch up) but yeah. Bots - not even humans - run around and try to find known exploits. Happens and is sadly like this. But there simply is nothing one can do to stop that.

Comment: @TomTom, do you think that using fail2ban is worthy in this case?  Why not block any IP that is snooping around like this?

Comment: It is worthy, but it won't do a lot. It also has a risk of hitting bad links to you that you may want to redirect to the homepage. lots of work.